# $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a function , $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge 3\|x-y\| , \forall x,y \in \mathbb R^2$ ; is $f(\mathbb R^2)$ open in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces, open-map

Let $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a function such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge 3\|x-y\| , \forall x,y \in \mathbb R^2$ , then is it true that $f$ maps open sets of $\mathbb R^2$ to open sets of $\mathbb R$ ? I can show that $f$ maps open sets to open sets in $f(\mathbb R^2)$ , so to prove the claim we only need to show that $f(\mathbb R^2)$ is open in $\mathbb R$ . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want for $f$ to be continuous? If not, then the statement isn't true, I think.

Comment: @jwsiegel : No .. $f$ is not necessarily continuous ...

Comment: @sandwich: There is no continuous function satisfying the hypothesis of the OP.

Comment: @PhoemueX : Well that's a pretty strong claim , can you please explain why ? And what about the original question ?

Comment: @SaunDev: Any function satisfying your hypothesis is injective. But there is no continuous injection $f : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$, by **invariance of domain** (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). Note that invariance of domain is a very "high level" theorem. There is probably an easier way to see that this is true. The exact argument is as follows: If $f$ was continuous, then so would be $g : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2, x \mapsto (f(x),0)$, so by invariance of domain, $g$ would be an open map, which is clearly false.

Comment: @PhoemueX : Yes .., I realized that is indeed true ; now what about the original question ?

Comment: @SaunDev: I think I have a counterexample, which I might post later this evening. May I ask why you are interested in this (fascinating) question? i.e., do you have a particular problem which you could solve if the statement was true?

Comment: @PhoemueX : Do please post the counterexample,and no,it is not related to some other problem,just out of intrinsic interest .. this "reverse Lipscitz" type condition do pop up many where ... 
And by the way for the fact that an injective continuous function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ cannot be continuous,I do have an elementary way out; let $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous injection; then $f:\mathbb R^2 \to f(\mathbb R^2)$ is a continuous bijection with $f(\mathbb R^2)$ connected in $\mathbb R$ , so an interval ; then for three distinct points $a,b,c \in \mathbb R^2$ ...

Comment: @PhoemueX : ... (continued) $f:\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{a,b,c\} \to f(\mathbb R^2)\setminus \{f(a),f(b),f(c)\}$ is a continuous bijection ; the domain is connected , but the range is an interval in $\mathbb R$ minus exactly three points in it , so  it cannot be an interval in $\mathbb R$ so cannot be connected , contradiction ! So an injective function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ cannot be continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sense, your claim is true. For every such map, $f(\Bbb{R}^2) \subset \Bbb{R}$ is open, simply because **there is no such map**.

To see this, note that $f$ is injective, so that $f^{-1} : M \to \Bbb{R}^2$ is well-defined and surjective, with $M := f(\Bbb{R}^2)$. But for $x,y \in M$, we have $x = f(x')$ and $y = f(y')$ for certain $x',y' \in \Bbb{R}^2$. Hence,
$$
\|f^{-1}(x)  - f^{-1}(y)\| = \| x' - y'\| \leq \frac{1}{3} |f(x') -f( y')| = \frac{1}{3} |x-y|,
$$
so that $f^{-1} : M \to \Bbb{R}^2$ is Lipschitz continuous and surjective, where $M \subset \Bbb{R}$ (already suspicious).

But by Kirszbraun's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirszbraun_theorem, in the current special case, it is not hard to prove it, since we can consider each component individually), we can find a Lipschitz-continuous extension $g : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^2$ of $f^{-1}$.

Consider this as a map $g : \Bbb{R} \times \{0\} \subset \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ (and, using Kirszbraun's theorem, extend it to a Lipschitz continuous map $h : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$).

It is well-known that Lipschitz maps from $\Bbb{R}^n$ to $\Bbb{R}^n$ map null-sets to null-sets (this is also not hard to see directly, using the fact that a null-set can be covered by countably many cubes $Q_n$ with $\sum_n vol(Q_n) < \varepsilon$ for arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ and that the image of a cube under a Lipschitz map $\Phi$ satisfies $\lambda(\Phi(Q)) \leq (10 \cdot C)^n \lambda(Q)$, where $C$ is the Lipschitz-consatnt and $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure).

Hence, we conclude that $\Bbb{R}^2 = f^{-1}(M) = g(M) = h(M \times \{0\}) \subset h(\Bbb{R}\times \{0\})$ is a null-set in $\Bbb{R}^2$, a contradiction.

Comment: For that assertion that Lipscitz map carries null sets to null sets ; shouldn't we have the map as $g:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ , i.e. the domain and co-domain with same dimension ?

Comment: I think that difficulty can be avoided yeah , you got $g$ Lipscitz on a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ so we can extend it to a Lipscitz function on $\mathbb R^2$ by the same Kirszbraun theorem ..... and yesterday you told about a counter-example ... what happened to that :) ?

Comment: @SaunDev: I edited my post to account for the additional extension of $g$ to $\Bbb{R}^2$. Here is what happened to the counterexample: When I tried to write it down formally, I noticed that my construction did not work. Then, when thinking about it, I tried to start with any such map and modify it so its image lies in $\Bbb{R} \setminus \Bbb{Q}$. To this end, I first had to get any map satisfying your conditions. After some thinking, I came up with the above proof which shows that there is no such map.

Comment: Ok , so that's what happened ... Indeed it came to me as a great surprise ..., non-existence of such a innocent looking class of functions ... Thanks for sharing your thoughts ..